What is the expected overlap between two random unit complex vectors of length $L$?
Given two random, uniformly sampled unit vectors $v_1, v_2 \in \mathbb{C}^L$, what is the expected value of their overlap $\langle v_1, v_2 \rangle$? I need a formula to calculate this value, given the length $L$ of these vectors, but I don't know how to approach this problem.

The vector $v_2$ is as likely to occur as $-v_2$ is. And, for a given $v_1$, we have $\langle v_1, v_2 \rangle + \langle v_1, -v_2 \rangle = 0$. So the expected value is $0$.

That makes sense. I think I incorrectly formulated my question. Would the reasoning be different if we were sampling each component of these vectors uniformly and independently, and at the end normalizing each vector, instead of sampling these vectors "as a whole"?

No, the same argument applies. The vector $-v_2$ is just as likely to be selected as $v_2$, even with that sampling method. However, there is an (almost never) chance that all components of the pre-normalized vector are $0$, in which case you can't normalize it. So the sampling is not always valid.
